# How can I see a list of active Network Filters (NDIS?) on my Windows 10 PC

Tags: networking, windows-10

Apologies if I am not using the correct terminology.

I would like to see the current/active list of network filters running on my Windows 10 PC.  (i.e. filters injected via Antivirus software for network filtering etc)

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `netsh wfp show filters`. This will create a file in the current directory named `filters.xml` containing information on all of the currently active network filters.